# How do I turn "Code Complete" back on in the IOS SDK for a single project?

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk

This is a very stupid question.

I am working in a project and all the "Code Complete" stopped working. Also most of the color coding stopped showing up. I have coped the code into a new project and it works fine. It is only in this one project it is not working.

I do not know how I did this and I cannot find anything on the web about this.

How do I  turn  "Code Complete" back on in the IOS SDK for a single project?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode occasionally has a problem with it's CodeSense API, whereby it will 'shut down', refuse to highlight anything but primitive types, then refuse to autocomplete anything but simple C modifiers.  There is only one fix I've found:

Go into the organizer: (shift+apple+2)>projects>//your project name//>derived data.  Delete derived data (it's just build logs, outputs, standard stuff that can be replaced).  Quit Xcode, then reopen and voila!  CodeSense turns back on!

Comment: usually i dont even need to quit xcode for this to work.  if this doesnt work, then also check to make sure the file is still in the compile sources of your project settings.  lately they disappear randomly on me.

Comment: I've found that when dragging in code from other projects, you have to make sure that your app is checked as a target, or it won't add it to the compile list.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I got most of it fixed but one .m file. I had to make a new .m file copy the code into that one, delete the old one and rename the new one the same as the old one.